# Webforms rebuild and use previous browser instance

Tags: asp.net, webforms

- VS2013 Upd1, .NET 4.5, Webforms

In the past I have been able to RUN (F5 or run button) my project and do some testing. I have then been able to stop the project (Shift-F5 or stop button). Make some code changes and BUILD the project (F6) and press reload in the browser and see what the changes are. Yes no debugging but I did not have to re RUN the project.

However the above behaviour has changed in that I have to always RUN my project after stopping it instead of reload in the browser. I am sure I have changed a setting somewhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the "Edit and Continue" setting.

Please see the answer to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808645/keeping-web-application-attached-to-iis-express-in-visual-studio-2013) similar question

Comment: you're a legend! Worked like a dream.